# how to stacked bar plot from frequency table?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

i have freq table like this

```
drug_name       reason_quit  quit_freq contuniue_freq     quit_percent
drug1           reason1      388            707           0.55
drug1           reason2       50            707           0.07
drug1           reason3       47            707           0.07
```

so, ı want to create stacked bar plot with quit_freq and contunie_freq by reason variable. also I will add percent text top of bar but if I can create grahp I can handle that.

reproduction data code

```
example<-data.frame(drug_name=c("drug1","drug1","drug1"),reason_quit=c("reason1","reason2","reason3"),
                    quit_freq=c(388,50,47),contuniue_freq=c(707,707,707),quit_percent=c(0.55,0.07,0.07))
```

my code for graph

```
example%>%dplyr::filter(drug_name=="drug1") %>% dplyr::select(c(-drug_name,-quit_percent)) %>% tidyr::pivot_longer(-reason_quit) %>% 
  
  ggplot(aes(x = birakma_sebebi, y = value, fill = name)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",position = "stack")
```

[image: the plot]

You can see the maxiumum of bar must  be 707 but in graph not.
any help ı will appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try enabling `fill` in `position` for stacking:

```
library(ggplot2)  
#Code
example%>%
  dplyr::filter(drug_name=="drug1") %>% 
  dplyr::select(c(-drug_name,-quit_percent)) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-reason_quit) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = reason_quit, y = value, fill = name)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",position = "fill")+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

Output:

[image]

If you want the scale around 700, you should dodge the bars like this:

```
#Code 2
example%>%
  dplyr::filter(drug_name=="drug1") %>% 
  dplyr::select(c(-drug_name,-quit_percent)) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-reason_quit) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = reason_quit, y = value, fill = name)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",position = position_dodge())
```

Output:

[image]

And if you want to see a stack bar until 700, you should compute the difference between you main variables like this:

```
#Code 3
example%>%
  mutate(diff_contuniue_freq=contuniue_freq-quit_freq) %>%
  dplyr::filter(drug_name=="drug1") %>% 
  dplyr::select(c(-drug_name,-quit_percent)) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-reason_quit) %>%
  filter(name!='contuniue_freq') %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = reason_quit, y = value, fill = name)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",position = 'stack')
```

Output:

[image]

And in order to add percentages, you can do in the same pipeline:

```
#Code 4
example%>%
  mutate(diff_contuniue_freq=contuniue_freq-quit_freq) %>%
  dplyr::filter(drug_name=="drug1") %>% 
  dplyr::select(c(-drug_name,-quit_percent)) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-reason_quit) %>%
  filter(name!='contuniue_freq') %>%
  group_by(reason_quit) %>%
  mutate(pos=sum(value),percent=paste0(100*round(value[name=='quit_freq']/pos,2),'%')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = reason_quit, y = value, fill = name)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",position = 'stack')+
  geom_text(aes(y=pos,label=percent),vjust=-0.25)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: thanks for good answer and added percent text. last question if ı want to group wtih drugs name in one plot how can ı do ?

ı have 18 drugs to represent that but  in one plot to do,getting complex for looking plot. just curios is that way?

Comment: @FatihEkici Hi. You can use `facet_wrap()` to create the plot for multiple drugs, which is easy as you add in the final part of the code. I hope that helped you!